# WoL stopped working for ASUS PN50 Mini PC after upgrade to lunar/23.04

Tags: networking, 23.04

Recently I upgraded my ASUS PN50 Mini PC from kinetic/22.10. to lunar/23.04
and since then Wake-on-LAN stopped working. Before and after the upgrade
WoL was (and still is) enabled in the BIOS. When the PN50 is running I can also
see that the WoL packet is received:

```
# ngrep '\xff{6}(.{6})\1{15}' -x port 9
interface: enp2s0f0 (192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0)
filter: ( port 9 ) and ((ip || ip6) || (vlan && (ip || ip6)))
match (JIT): \xff{6}(.{6})\1{15}
#
U 192.168.0.37:54759 -> 255.255.255.255:9 #1
  ff ff ff ff ff ff f0 2f    74 c3 ee d5 f0 2f 74 c3    ......./t..../t.
  ee d5 f0 2f 74 c3 ee d5    f0 2f 74 c3 ee d5 f0 2f    .../t..../t..../
  74 c3 ee d5 f0 2f 74 c3    ee d5 f0 2f 74 c3 ee d5    t..../t..../t...
  f0 2f 74 c3 ee d5 f0 2f    74 c3 ee d5 f0 2f 74 c3    ./t..../t..../t.
  ee d5 f0 2f 74 c3 ee d5    f0 2f 74 c3 ee d5 f0 2f    .../t..../t..../
  74 c3 ee d5 f0 2f 74 c3    ee d5 f0 2f 74 c3 ee d5    t..../t..../t...
  f0 2f 74 c3 ee d5                                     ./t...
```

Before and after the upgrade a wol-service was (and still is) in place that
enables WoL at startup through ethtool:

```
[Unit]
Description=Configure Wake-up on LAN

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/ethtool -s enp2s0f0 wol g
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

The status of the service seems ok:

```
$ sudo service wol status
● wol.service - Configure Wake-up on LAN
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wol.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2023-06-03 07:05:03 CEST; 1min 16s ago
    Process: 932 ExecStart=/sbin/ethtool -s enp2s0f0 wol g (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 932 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms
```

`ethtool` also confirms that WoL is enabled:

```
# ethtool enp2s0f0
Settings for enp2s0f0:
    ...
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    ...
```

Also other system settings seem to confirm this:

```
# lspci -tv
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
           ...
           +-02.1-[02]--+-00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           |            +-00.1  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111xP UART #1
           |            +-00.2  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111xP UART #2
           |            +-00.3  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111xP IPMI interface
           |            \-00.4  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL811x EHCI host controller
           ...
# cat /proc/acpi/wakeup 
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GPP0      S4    *disabled
GPP1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.2
GPP2      S4    *disabled
GPP3      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:02.1 <-- should be the network dev according to lspci above
GPP4      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:02.2
GPP5      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:02.3
GP17      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
XHC0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:05:00.3
XHC1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:05:00.4
GP18      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.2
GP19      S4    *disabled
# cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:02.1/power/wakeup
enabled
```

I do not find anything suspicious in the logs, but I actually also do not know exactly what to look out for.

Any ideas on how to fix this (or maybe just to debug this further)?

Comment: Great minds think alike Volker, I literally have done this exact same process today on my PN50 and am at a loss because my WoL has also broken for seemingly no reason!

Comment: @ColdFish good to hear that it is not just me :-). So for you it was not even related to a distribution or kernel upgrade?

Comment: I went from Windows 10 on my PN50 (with WoL working) to Ubuntu 23.04.  As appears to be the case with you, there is seemingly no reason I can see as to why my PN50 shouldn’t have WoL enabled.  Everything on the Ubuntu end appears to be set as intended (as it does for you), it just simply doesn’t work and I have no idea how to debug it .

Comment: I don't know much about WoL, but I would try to use the kernel used before the upgrade, or if there are any errors on kernel boot logs, `journalctl -b -k -p err`

Comment: Gave that a go Pablo and I can't see much difference between the two boot outputs.  [22.04 journalctl output here](https://pastebin.com/mL7exFfT) and [23.04 boot output here](https://pastebin.com/jXVM21dg).

Comment: @PabloBianchi Thanks for the response and sorry for the delay. I also tried this out and indeed when I boot with the previous kernel (Ubuntu 5.19.0-42.43-generic 5.19.17) and poweroff, WoL works, while with the current kernel (Ubuntu 6.2.0-20.20-generic 6.2.6) it does not. I also checked with the proposed journalctl both boot-logs (actually even down to `-p notice`) and did not see any significant differences. Will try to investigate this further (tips welcome :-). At least I have a workaround now.